# Take next don't skip previous LINQ c#

Tags: c#, jquery, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create Infinite scrolling in my project.

**Scene-**

I have about 100 pictures to render on my view page. For every scroll to bottom request I am sending LINQ take value by jQuery-

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var value = 0;
        function IncreasedValue() {
            value += 10;
            return value;
        }
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 10) {

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Home/FunHome/?valuetake=' + IncreasedValue() + '&valueskip=' + "0",
                    type: 'GET',
                    datatype: 'HTML',
                    success: function (data) {

                        $('#funhome-partial').html(data);

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

It is always increased by `+10` When scrolled to bottom.

At first time load My action retrieves 5 records and skips none(Working fine). As soon as `takevalue` in increased by 10, I am parsing this value to LINQ `Take()`.

```
public ActionResult FunHome(int? valueskip, int? valuetake) {
    if (valuetake == null && valueskip == null) {
        int take = 5;
        int skip = 0;

        var cardlist = (from u in db.CardTables
                        select new CardModel {
                            cardDate = u.CardDate,
                            cardFileName = u.CardFileName,
                            cardFilePath = u.CardFilePath,
                            cardHashCode = u.CardHashCode,
                            cardID = u.CardID,
                            cardTitle = u.CardTitle

                        }).Take(take).Skip(skip);

        return View(cardlist);
    }
    else {
        int skip = 0;
        int take = Convert.ToInt32(valuetake);
        var cardlist = (from u in db.CardTables
                        select new CardModel {
                            cardDate = u.CardDate,
                            cardFileName = u.CardFileName,
                            cardFilePath = u.CardFilePath,
                            cardHashCode = u.CardHashCode,
                            cardID = u.CardID,
                            cardTitle = u.CardTitle

                        }).Take(take).Skip(skip);
        return PartialView("FunHome", cardlist);

    }
}
```

Currently what is happening is when ajax query asks for 10 records, This action retrieves those next 10 records and renders all the page again by taking all asked records.

This slows down my application because of rendering all the records on every scroll to bottom event.

**Note-**

I don't want to skip previous records as obvious all the pictures should be displayable.

Is there any way of loading only next records that I can achieve this with `LINQ` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `Skip`/`Take` methods should always be used in that order: `Skip` and then `Take` when used for paging.
2. `Skip(0)` is pointless...
3. You should only return new elements from your query and append them to your page instead of replacing entire HTML content. Use `append()` instead of `html()` in you javascript code.
4. You can prepare your query definition before `if`/`else` and then just apply proper `Skip`/`Take` combination to prevent code repetition.

```
public ActionResult FunHome(int? valueskip, int? valuetake) {

    var query = (from u in db.CardTables
                 select new CardModel {
                     cardDate = u.CardDate,
                     cardFileName = u.CardFileName,
                     cardFilePath = u.CardFilePath,
                     cardHashCode = u.CardHashCode,
                     cardID = u.CardID,
                     cardTitle = u.CardTitle
                 });

    if (valuetake == null && valueskip == null) {
        int take = 5;

        var cardlist = query.Take(take);

        return View(cardlist);
    }
    else {
        int skip = Convert.ToInt32(valueskip);
        int take = Convert.ToInt32(valuetake);

        var cardlist = query.Skip(skip).Take(take);

        return PartialView("FunHome", cardlist);
    }
}
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var value = 0;
        function IncreasedValue() {
            value += 10;
            return value;
        }
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 10) {
                var currentValue = value;
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Home/FunHome/?valuetake=' + IncreasedValue() + '&valueskip=' + currentValue,
                    type: 'GET',
                    datatype: 'HTML',
                    success: function (data) {

                        $('#funhome-partial').append(data);

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```